# What is the default color code for selected values in drop down lists?

Tags: css

I'm trying to add color to an element to match the default color of selected values in drop down lists.  What is the color code for this?  I can't seem to find any information online.

Answer (score 0):

Use this type css

```
ul > li.active > a, ul > li > a:hover,  ul > li > a:focus       {
  color:black; /*as you wish*/
 }
```